# Partial answer in comments

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I have recently asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984798/exc-bad-access-code-2-on-cccrypt). 1 answer solved my issue partially, but the answerer helped in solving the rest of the issue in the question comments (not the answer comments). In fact most of his answer is on comments.

I have asked him to include those info in the answer and I am sure he will do it too. But I was just wondering what if he doesn't? Should we flag the comments or the answer to merge them with the original answer or can we simply ignore?

I am concerned because I have read in one of the question here that people don't usually read comments and since the answer was in question comments and not in answer comments, I am sure that it won't get enough eyeballs.

I couldn't find any similar question, so posted it here.

Comment: You can just edit the answer to add the info from the comments?

Comment: Answers-in-comments are becoming increasingly common, and increasingly annoying. It's as if more and more people are racing to be the first to "prove" they know how to fix the problem, but can't be bothered to write an actual answer and don't care enough about the SE model to just leave answering to somebody who _can_ be bothered to do so properly.

Comment: If someone answers in a comment, then collate, write _actual_ answer, and claim rep.  Give them a chance to do so themselves first out of courtesy. Job done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I may be guilty of this on occasion. My reasoning is for when I am not 100% sure my solution is one that will work -- perhaps their exact issue is on the cusp of my understanding but no one else is touching the particular question. Thus, I'll direct the user to what I believe is the answer but leave them to figure out the details themselves because I'm only 98% sure it will work.  Is this a bad approach? What should I do differently?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: You don't have to be 100% sure to post an answer. Downvotes exist! You'll soon find out if your answer is wrong. Anyway, it depends how you go about it: postulating something is different from shoving a three-word code solution in comments and leaving everyone else to clear up the mess :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe it is a language thing. I want to ask "have you tried xyz? It is likely to be your problem." but if I posted it as an answer I'd feel I should write it as "XYZ will fix your problem." Somehow I feel hesitant to answer questions that I'm not super confident about all the same. :(

Comment: @BlackVegetable: The former is borderline for me. The latter is definitely an answer. But my point is that if you are hesitant to answer a question, to the extent that you don't want to write an answer, _then don't write an answer_. Posting it instead in the comments doesn't fix anything :P Just let someone surer answer.

Comment: @BlackVegetable If your answer is wrong, you can always make edit to it or delete it entirely. Or you can mention that the answer is correct if the following condition happens. But in any case try to post it as an answer, if it's going to answer the question.

Comment: @BlackVegetable You can always answer *as if it were the case*. Say it "may be that...", give a situation where you would see this and show how to fix it, and why it was a problem. Even if it doesn't answer the OP's problem it should help someone else who has the problem you thought the OP had (who end up in that question via a google search).

Comment: @BlackVegetable: If you're 98% sure you have the answer, post as an answer. If you're 90% sure, do a quick sanity check, *then* post. It's only if you're really just guessing that it belongs in comments, and then not as an answer, but as a clarification to determine what the answer should be.

Comment: Amazing how many answers are to be found in the comments on the OP...

Comment: I love answering in comments whenever 1) the question has a trivial answer that's not worth earning rep over, or 2) the question is of low quality and likely to be closed but I want to help the OP anyways, or 3) I want to answer but let someone else get some rep, as I already have enough.  So if you see an answer in a comment from me and you think it's a good one, feel free to turn it into an answer and get some upvotes.

Comment: @aroth: I hope you're also voting to close it in case #2. Otherwise, you're contributing to the problem of questions that just get left open and unanswered forever. (When I do that, I usually even mention that I'm voting to close in the comment; I worry that seeing a comment that "someone" will "probably" come along and turn into answer may discourage others from voting to close…)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Wait for some time ( a few days as the answereer might have had urgent things that he needed to take care of, so couldn't edit the answer ), and if they still don't add the important parts in their answer, you can edit the answer. But please do not make drastic changes to the answer.

If the edit requires a lot of changes, then it's better to post your own answer giving the full details. You can take your time, organize everything and post a Good Quality answer.

By posting another answer, if you feel bad about gaining reputation due to someone else's effort, you can mention that your's is an extension of the other answer and mark your answer as community wiki so you don't feel bad.

Do not flag the comments or answer's as there is nothing wrong with them. Most of the time, users post comments because they cannot guarantee if that is the actual reason, and when the problem is confirmed, they can post the answers without fear.

Comment: Why not edit the answer? Adding your own leaves you a copy of the first answer with some extra info.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, there have been many discussions previosly that you should not make large scale edits on someone else's answer. You can leave comments to suggest edits, but large scale edits on answer's are discouraged, and will be rejected most of the time. The OP did the right thing by suggesting to make those edits in his comments. If the user who answered has no intention of making those edits, there's nothing wrong with posting another complete answer.

Comment: This is not a large scale edit where the original intent would be lost. This is adding a few lines of additional information.

Comment: If an answerer significantly improves their answer as a comment rather than editing their answer, perhaps just edit their question to append the improving comment to the original answer.