# Should I edit my answer to include a improvement from comments

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, comments

This has happened to me couple of times now:

I answer a question and then someone else leaves a comment which improves my answer a lot. Maybe the comment is minor in the sense that it won't change the overall approach of the answer but nevertheless makes it much better.

Here is a good example: [logical or on list of pandas masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132250/logical-or-on-list-of-pandas-masks/32133546#32133546)

Should I..

1) Leave the answer as it is. After all the better way is still visible in the comments.

2) Edit my original answer according to the comment.

3) Leave the original answer but append the commented thing in it.

---

Pros and cons:

1) + It's clear who contributed and what, - It feels stupid to leave sub-optimal things hanging around, maybe someone won't even notice the comment

2) + Imo clean and simple. - It shows that it's my answer but actually it benefited a lot from the comment. Of course I should still mention the commentators name but still..., can someone get offended if I do this?

3) + Everything is still visible. - Again I am leaving some sub-optimal stuff in there, which makes the answer unnecessarily long.

---

So what is the preferred way?

Comment: Edit it into your question. Give credit where appropriate.

Comment: Of interest: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292140/partial-answer-in-comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are second class citizens, and where possible we want to avoid answers or otherwise valuable information being contained totally within the comments.

So, you have two options:

- leave a comment encouraging the commenter to edit their information into your answer
- or edit it in yourself

You can acknowledge or credit the person who left the comment, [as suggested by Bill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303024/should-i-edit-my-answer-to-include-a-improvement-from-comments#comment236715_303024). But we also don't want excessive fluff in an answer, so don't overdo it. If editing the extra information in to the answer really troubles your conscience then you can always convert your answer to community wiki, which means you won't gain any rep from subsequent upvotes of your answer.