# Should code samples be tailored for readability or efficiency?

Tags: discussion, code

Posing this question resulting from a comment debate on my answer here: [send gmail using powershell - Current suggestions on S.O. are NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157841/send-gmail-using-powershell-current-suggestions-on-s-o-are-not-working/51158377#51158377)

When providing code samples on Stack Overflow, should readability or code efficiency be preferred?

In the example I gave above, I can see both cases. One should always strive to write good, clean code, and it is a good thing to incorporate early on when picking up a new language. Language standards are a thing, and in most cases, they eschew bad habits in favor of good ones. But on the other hand, sometimes the most efficient code doesn't lead to a clear, concise example and can lead to confusing (less readable) samples that may not be well-understood by a novice.

In my opinion, Stack Overflow is a <strike>learning tool</strike> knowledge repository, it is up to the user/developer to implement their code efficiently. Code samples should be readable and each answer should be clear and concise, preferring readability where possible. But do others share this sentiment?

Comment: _"In my opinion, StackOverflow is a learning tool"_ in before "Stack Overflow is not a learning tool." In all seriousness, though, I don't see why others should be able to dictate how _you_ decide to present your answers. If they thing another way is better/more efficient/prettier/more correct, they should be posting their own answer. (Attributed as needed, and in their own words as needed, of course.) In other words, if your post is technically correct (the best kind of correct!) and in a style that makes you happy, why does it matter if others agree that it's the right style?

Comment: I came across such a scenario a few hours ago. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212865/9209546) solved OP's problem, but I wasn't entirely happy with the layout, so I proposed a [functionally identical alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213043/9209546), attributed the former answer, and turned it into a community wiki. Because perceptions of readability aren't clear-cut. Not sure if this was the "right way" to do it, but just thought I'd share.

Comment: @Kendra, what else would you call a Q&A site? It may not be a classroom nor should it be used as such (there are well thought out guidelines as to what is an appropriate question), but posters are asking questions they do not know the answers to. Although this is far from the topic of this post :)

Comment: Our primary focus is to build a repository of knowledge. Granted, when you are teaching you are also imparting knowledge but the structure of teaching and a repository aren't always aligned.

Comment: Fair enough, I like that. "Knowledge repository"

Comment: Whichever way is most useful, if you're only going to show the solution one way. It's possible that will vary depending on the question.

Comment: A good SO answer should not just be code anyway; you're supposed to explain what is happening in the code. So if you think some aspects of the code could be unclear, make sure to explain them in enough detail.

Comment: Voting to close this as POB because people are likely to be split starkly between the two and it's a matter of how you approach helping others, and especially because people can be quite militant about their view regarding this.

Comment: A related question of mine: [When the “Best Answer” is not always the “Right Answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363246/when-the-best-answer-is-not-always-the-right-answer)

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, answers should provide sensible, readable code, as in, code that you would want to use in a production environment.

This means: **don't overoptimize**! You don't have to pay for each line you write, and it's mainly the compilers job to make the code compact. If you fear RSI, don't use the minimal amount of characters to write your program, but just get an ergonomic keyboard.

If efficiency means scrapping three comparisons and making your code a giant, hard to-understand one-liner instead of splitting those comparisons out, and likely saving the users 1-2 milliseconds when running the program, **please don't**.

If efficiency means writing code natively instead of *using jQuery for that* (or using other external libraries), or other changes that *substantially* improve efficiency in a scenario where time might be relevant, then **please do**. We should encourage good, efficient coding practices, and not take shortcuts.

Though often I do like both giving *The easy way:* and *the proper way:*, if there are two obvious approaches, also pointing out why the proper way is better. This saves me from someone else posting the easy way and saying *hey, it's more simple than that previous answer = better*. A discussion if that should be one or two answers can be saved for a separate thread (probably two, but I often use one).

Often, optimizations that impact readability hardly make any difference on the compiled size or time to run code. To refer to the words of Donald Knuth: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*. And if you want to spread evil, you can always go to [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

While I can at least respect the desire to make your code performant and as optimized as it can be, consider the context you're in (so you don't break [the First Rule of Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?FirstRuleOfOptimization)).

Your answers should be as **illustrative** as they can be.  That is to say, it's entirely acceptable to have a question which is not incredibly performant so long as it clearly illustrates the solution so that anyone could understand it.  If one focuses solely on making it the most optimal solution they can, I fear they may have missed the point of answering questions at all.

Answer (score 2):

> Should code samples be tailored for readability or efficiency?

Both. But we aren't gods and we don't have eternity so just try to give the best you can using a time you are willing to spare.

> Code samples should be readable and each answer should be clear and concise, preferring readability where possible.

Because answers on SO are meant to be read (for some of us - voiced), the readability **is** the thing. We want easy to read **and understand** questions/answers.

What about efficiency? You may call "efficient" either a direct answer to the question, or with best performance, or maybe shortest and don't forget there is a production quality code. Those are four and therefore there are four candidates to the answer, which all can co-exists and help different people.

There are common traps and beginner mistakes. This is why you will see a comment or two about sql-injection under every answer with string concatenation for queries. Those comments are good. The comments themselves are already doing a good thing to the reader and as a user who seek help you have to read all comments anyway.

You question is basically about [whenever you must](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303024/1997232) change you answer. It depends how important comment is. If you think your answer is good (with or without it), then let it stay. But some actions may occur: comment upvoting, another answer "based on your" may appear, editing, downvoting, etc. You **must not**. Just be prepared that different people will act differently if your answer is suddenly not what **they** would answer.