# Should I comment or answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I often find that I comment something which is a correct answer to someone's question (albeit brief or with no explanation), but do not know exactly what to do. Others nudge me to create a proper answer, but should I? Is it encouraged to write an answer instead of leaving a helpful comment? It's not a matter of time for me, but I just don't really feel motivated by imaginary internet points, thus I feel a comment will do. I've read over [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335711/5647260) answer but I'm still not sure.

Should I comment or answer?

Comment: You are not obliged to answer, but what if someone comments back "thanks, solved"?

Comment: @RadLexus I move on. But is that a problem, not providing an answer and not marking that question 'solved' for future readers?

Comment: Oof - it would be [one of my pet peeves](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/updated-actively-prevent-this-in-title-not-solved-yet). Yet, Stack Overflow places heavy emphasis on "answered *and solved*".

Comment: @RadLexus I'm just wondering if having an a well received (and accepted answer) is better for the sake of future readers - thus meaning it would be better to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, a helpful comment to an on-topic question is better than nothing -- it may prove useful to the asker, as well as to others who might be willing to write answers. Not making such a comment into a proper answer, for whatever reason, is well within your rights. I would even add that any request for a proper answer more forceful than a gentle nudge would be inappropriate. That said...

> But is that a problem, not providing an answer and [not] marking that question 'solved' for future readers?

It is suboptimal, to the extent that an answer is a better medium for presenting a solution than a comment. For that reason, if the only issue is an unwillingness to chase "imaginary internet points", it is better to just shape it into an answer.

---

Personally, these days I only post answers as comments in a few fairly specific scenarios:

- Crucial hints for non-closable beginner or homework questions for which I don't feel like providing a fuller solution.
- Brief clarifications for benign closable questions (i.e. typo questions and non-obvious duplicates).
- Potential or speculative solutions which I regard, at the moment of posting, as unsatisfactory and not worthy of a full answer.

Answer (score 10):

## Always write an answer.

Nothing else matters in the eyes of Stack Overflow.*

<sup>*: That is, comments aren't indexed and can't be easily found by others.  It's also not the way you gain any meaningful standing with the site.</sup>

Comment: I disagree with this. In most cases, you should be writing an answer, but there are some cases where it is clear that the question will be closed, even though the answer is simple and one comment from you will fix the whole problem.

Comment: If the question is set to be closed, that implies that it *shouldn't* be answered @user1280483. This means even in comments.

Comment: @Makoto I still disagree - if the question is caused by a typo, then of course it should be closed as "caused by a typo" but it would be pointless (and counterproductive) not to write a comment saying what the typo is.

Comment: For that matter, I have often left comments explaining e.g. *why* a particular linked duplicate applies. Sometimes the question is really two questions and each is a duplicate; I'll leave a one-sentence comment to say "to do XY, do X (see first linked duplicate) and then do Y with the X results (see second linked duplicate)". Questions like this are *rarely* deserving of an answer (only when the XY combination is non-obvious and commonly asked about).

Comment: @kaya3: The problem is that can't scale. Sure, leaving a comment on a question or two is probably innocuous in and of itself, but you can't reasonably expect that to be "the norm" for tens of thousands of questions. So, the prevailing guidance is still to answer the question when it's on topic and close when it's not.

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder text in the comment box reads:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Seems quite clear that it is undesired to answer questions in the comment area.

Apart from voting to close the question (duplicate, typo, ...), you could copy the relevant texts from the comment section into a community wiki answer, starting with "As stated in comments...", or you just use your own words.