# Should attempts to answer a question through comments be flagged?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, comments

I see many people attempting to answer the OP by commenting the question.

In my opinion this is not the right thing to do, I think people are afraid to post a too short answer, or afraid of getting downvotes, or they just think that commenting is the fastest way to help the OP.

But the question is: Is it all right to permit users to make these attempts?
If no, and since there isn't a flag of kind: "attempt to answer", what should we do in these cases?

Comment: If you flagged it, what would you expect to happen? Do you want a moderator to delete it? Then you've helped no one. You've actually made the situation worse.

Comment: Just to know, I never flagged comments in these situations. In fact, there are comments that are authentic answers, and the OP recognizes the comment as an solution, thank the commenter and then leave the post without an accepted answer

Comment: You are asking "should [they] be flagged?" I am asking you, what good would possibly come out of flagging them?

Comment: Flagging may alert the user that he needs to transform his comment into a answer

Comment: Flags don't alert users, they alert moderators.

Comment: My answer to the question in the is that such comments definitely should not be flagged. Reasons for that are implied in my answer to [*Should I comment or answer?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339394/2751851)

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, **I would want a moderator to delete it**. Comments can not be downvoted, so answers posted in comments are exempt from the usual voting quality controls that apply to answers. I often see "guess" answers posted as comments that are totally incorrect, so I disagree with your claims that this would help no one and make the situation worse.

Answer (score 7):

There are quite a few cases in which users straight up do not want to post the (possible) solution as an answer. Those include low quality questions, known dupes etc.

Chances are, if you post an answer to one of those questions, you'll lose more rep then you gain, and it looks pretty bad. I personally wouldn't want to be known for being the FGITW. It's also possible that the users trying to help are unsure whether the solution they came up with is actually viable.

Normally I'd say that one should simply flag/VTC those questions, and move on, but in some cases I find myself in a spot where I feel like help is warranted despite the question being bad. In such cases I try to help using the comment function, possibly even by answering the question there.

---

**TL;DR:** *Flagging comments like that doesn't help anyone. If a question has no answer, but has been answered in the comments, feel free to crop the answer & post it as community wiki. Otherwise I'd not touch those comments.*

Comment: I don't feel like this answer is acceptable because it does nothing to discourage the practice of using comments for the answers.  In fact, it basically just says "Seth sometimes likes to use the comments to answer questions", even though it's something explicitly discouraged in the [help text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) shown when you earn the comment privileges!  (see - **When shouldn't I comment?** section)

Comment: If you answer a low quality question that gets deleted, any rep you lost from downvotes will also be reverted. You can also wait a little bit and delete your own answer to restore any lost rep.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic The existence of answers can prevent a question from being automatically deleted. It is patently worse to post an answer to a question that should be deleted than it is to post an answer in the comment form. It is also worse to post an answer that isn't really a solution than it is to post a possible solution as a comment if you're unsure of whether or not it is applicable. There are lots of situations where posting a comment that could be interpreted as an attempt to answer the question is better than outright posting an answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant: But there are no situations where posting an answer as a comment is better than posting *neither* an answer nor a comment. That's the overall problem; this all comes off as sanctioning the practice rather than denouncing it.

Comment: @NicolBolas i completely disagree not only with your assertion, but also with the notion that the practice is in need of denouncing. Sure posting answers as comments is discouraged, but thats a long way from "publicly declare to be wrong or evil" (the definition of denounce)

Comment: @TinyGiant: "*i completely disagree not only with your assertion*" OK, provide a scenario where posting an answer as a comment is better *for the site* than posting nothing at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas I already did that in my first comment here.

Comment: @TinyGiant: No, you compared answering as an answer to answering as a comment. I'm asking you to compare answering as a comment to *posting nothing*.

Comment: @Nicol sure, any situation where the comment has any information of value would be a situation where posting the comment would be better than not. You should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384217.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I have read it. And I disagree *vehemently* with it. Things like that are precisely what I'm talking about with regard to "sanctioning the practice". It's little more than saying "go ahead and answer as a comment. It's fine."

Comment: @NicolBolas that's ok, you're allowed to be wrong. This discussion is getting quite off-topic and doesn't seem to be going anywhere productive so I'm out

Comment: @TinyGiant: As long as you agree that by this stance, you are *sanctioning* the practice of answering through comments. And I suspect you've never had to deal with a low-traffic tag corrupted by a person who prefers to answer through comments, to the point where the "unanswered" tab is utterly useless.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sanction (verb): "give official permission or approval for". I'm not official, but I would generally approve of giving permission to use the comment field when posting an answer is not the best idea, or when the user posting the comment is unsure of whether or not the proposed solution is applicable to the problem at hand. Note that I'm not suggesting that everyone and their dogs should stop using the answer form altogether, I'm just saying that there are situations where doing so is the least bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes give hints to solve a question in form of comments because I'm not sure of it or because it's rather incomplete but I want to help nevertheless.

Rarely do I see more or less complete answers in comments. Then I comment on it and urge the commenter to convert the comment into a full fledged answer.

Even more rarely, if the commenter is not inclined to do so, I write an answer copying the comment and giving proper attribution.

Solutions to questions should exist preferably as answers though because otherwise the quality control is somewhat circumvented. Additionally, comments are second class citizens and may get deleted any time.

That means that there would be an argument for an intervention, possibly a reminder that answers should be posted as answers or what comments are for. However, the differentiation between a mere hint and posting of full answers might be very difficult, the number of occurrences is rather low in my experience and it's very difficult to actually give a high quality answer to a question within the very limited comment space. That's why I think that there is no need for that currently.

Just comment on good answers posted as comments and encourage the commenters to post full answers or use the comment in your own answer giving attribution, so that people can up- and down-vote on it.