# Should we flag comments that are only posted as "quick answers"?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

It's written in [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) that comments are not recommended for answering:

> When shouldn't I comment?
>
> ...
>
> - **Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer**; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);

Yet, for questions that are simple/easy to answer we're very likely to see users quickly answering them in the comments.  And often these comments collect a few upvotes, too, I've seen this again and again.

Should those comments be flagged? Or just ignored?  If they should be flagged, which reason should be selected?

- Usually someone posts an answer at the same time, or shortly thereafter, and the comment has become **obsolete**.
- Sometimes people won't bother to answer because there is already an upvoted answer in the comments, and we get an abandoned question, perhaps it's **not constructive** for the site.
- Or, we could select **other...** and reference the section where it lists the reasons to use comments.

Comment: Related questions: [*Should attempts to answer a question through comments be flagged?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340572/2751851) -- [*Answerers who only use comments*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/2751851) -- [*Should I comment or answer?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339394/2751851)

Comment: No, you shouldn't flag comments that answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to flag such answers by themselves.

If you want to do something about such comment:

- comment shows that question really should be closed (typo, duplicate, too broad) - act on question appropriately
- convert comment into high quality answer, don't forget to credit author of the comment. Pick between community wiki (if essentially copy-pasted comment into answer) or answering yourself (if providing clarifications/rewriting/adding details on top of the comment). Flag comment as obsolete/other (see next point). More discussion - [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)
- if there are existing answers - flag as obsolete if comment clearly covered by answers  or "other: comment already converted to answer/covered by other answer".
- consider to up-vote comment and move on.

Comment: To clarify, I was asking about flagging the comments.  Updated title to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it be helpful. It's also been conversely pointed out to me that some of my answers are redundant with good points in comments when I haven't had time to review them all for busy posts.

Comment: I've also found that when joining a new community I'm unable to comment. Even though my suggestion would be minor tweak to an existing answer I have to add it as a separate one. Would it also be possible to flag/migrate novice answers to comments of the relevant answer?

Comment: You should not refrain yourself from posting a *good* answer where you explain *with your own words* something that's already in comments (and not already in existing answers): answers are what matters for the site - comments are just ephemeral chatter which can disappear at any time. // You can comment once you get 50 rep.