# How can I convince that a technically incorrect comment is equivalent to a bad answer which is not to be followed and deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer, specific-comment, moderator-intervention

How can I convince that this technically incorrect comment is equivalent to a bad answer which is not to be followed and deleted?

The discussion thread referred in question is [Locator is not found on robot framework for Click Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265823/locator-is-not-found-on-robot-framework-for-click-button)

Two of the comments in this discussion are as follows :

Comment 1 :

> If you use geckodriver, you might be facing that problem, If you use legacy firefox driver, you wouldn't be facing any problem, would you like me to give the code which uses Legacy driver of Firefox?

Comment 2 :

> HI, I checked with legacy driver in firefox and this simple code driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitCreate")).click works very fine.

I have marked both the comments for *In need of Moderator Intervention* referring the following comments from the discussion [Filling out form with Selenium works on Chrome but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197699/filling-out-form-with-selenium-works-on-chrome-but-not-firefox)

> Please don't use the legacy Firefox driver, it is deprecated and will not be supported in the near future. -- titusfortner
>
> I can in no way endorse an answer that advises to use legacy, unmaintained, unsupported, to-be-removed software. Make no mistake, future visitors to this question, this is a bad answer and its advice should not be followed. -- JimEvans [core contributor to the [Selenium](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive) web automation framework]
>
> I am sorry to say I can't imagine in my dreams an answer still suggests the unmaintained, unsupported, to-be-removed Legacy Driver. This is definitely a bad answer and needs to be avoided at all cost. -- DebanjanB

My *In need of Moderator Intervention* flags :

For Comment 1 :

> Even aftr warn frm JimEvans abt Legacy Driver being unmaintained in stackoverflow.com/questions/50197699/… user still suggests same – DebanjanB 4 hours ago   declined

For Comment 2 :

> Even aftr warn frm JimEvans abt Legacy Driver being unmaintained in stackoverflow.com/questions/50197699/… user still suggests same – DebanjanB 4 hours ago   declined

These comments are found useful by half a dozen of community users.

But the *In need of Moderator Intervention* flag for both the comments *to get deleted* within the discussion [Locator is not found on robot framework for Click Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265823/locator-is-not-found-on-robot-framework-for-click-button) was declined without any reason being specified.

Was my approach rational and in sync with our all around efforts to maintain the standards Stack Overflow follows?

Comment: you flag comments as no longer needed..

Comment: @SurajRao I was about to say that we don't flag comments for their lack of accuracy. Should a moderator treat obsolete/noisy comments and inaccurate ones the same way?

Comment: @E_net4 not sure how accuracy comes in comments. Since they should otherwise be an answer. The comments are definitely useless

Comment: Ok, after seeing the flag text: What do you want the mod to do? Delete the comment? Suspend the user? Upvote the other comments? Kill a puppy? Your flag isn't actionable which is a reason to decline it.

Comment: @rene surely not _the_ puppy?

Comment: That said: I'm not even sure if silencing users this way is the best way forward. In this case it might be warranted but don't apply that tactic for everything you dislike

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, *the* puppy. You think that brings trouble?

Comment: @rene Hurting puppies is wrong, I'm going to flag your comment. :P

Comment: On a tangential note, I would say your comment in that answer was unnecessary. It adds no information not in the previous two comments (one of them, as you note, from a core contributor and thus as authoritative as we'd like). It would have been better to refrain from posting it, to avoid piling on and protracted discussions, and also for pragmatic reasons: if there is a really important comment that should be highlighted, it is especially useful to make the comments as tidy as possible, as only the five most upvoted comments are displayed by default. In such cases, just upvote and move on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't flag something for technical accuracy ([related post for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)). That's what votes and comments are for.

Mods are not expected to have domain knowledge about any given topic, so any flags you raise should not require domain knowledge to be validated and handled.

You can:

- #### Flag it for being an answer posted as a comment.

  You can consider the problem to be that it's a (partial) answer posted as a comment instead of that the answer is wrong. If an answer were wrong, you'd be able to downvote it or properly comment on it to indicate problems with it.

  I would generally only recommend flagging comments as such if there's already an answer posted giving roughly the same advice, which you should also note in your flag. This is obviously a flawed strategy, since any given comment may not have been posted as an answer, especially if it's particularly bad advice, but any given mod may not want to delete a comment that could potentially be useful, so your flag could otherwise get declined.

  > This comment should be deleted because it is an attempt to answer the question and someone already recommended using [...] in an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201148/1711796.
- #### Reply to the comment pointing out the problem with the approach.

  Be sure to note that they shouldn't be posting answers as comments.

  > I would not recommend [...] because [...]. If you still believe it's a good approach, or you would like to elaborate on why you recommend it, please instead post it as an answer for increased visibility, to enable others to comment and vote on it and to allow it to be edited.

Comment: "I would generally only recommend flagging comments as such if there's already an answer posted giving roughly the same advice (because any given mod may not want to delete a comment that could be useful)." So comments giving terrible advice that no one is willing to put forth in an answer just stick around forever?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Pretty much. In a perfect system, we'd treat all comments posted as answers the same, but in the real world your flags might get declined if you do that.

Comment: I suddenly have a lot more sympathy for RPG SE's brutally unforgiving policy of deleting every answer posted as a comment on sight.

Comment: Unless the information was already posted as an answer, I don't believe flagging answers in comments is a good idea, and not just due to pragmatic reasons. If the comment is useful, it is not worth it to get rid of it; if it is not useful (as in this case), you still can't expect a mod to decide on its technical merits, as you point out. Cf. [the comments to *Should attempts to answer a question through comments be flagged?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340572/2751851)

Comment: As duplode states, your first bullet point will most likely lead to your flag being declined. I decline almost all flags complaining about answers being posted in comments. If a comment attempts to provide useful information, I'm generally not going to delete it. The few cases where I will remove such comments are when someone has provided the same content in an answer, and the comments are now obsolete, but I won't act as a proxy to decide who is and is not technically correct in comments.