# Why were my comment flags declined for comments that provided answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

After answering a question, I NLN (No Longer Needed) flagged two comments under said question that provided an answer (pretty much the same answer as mine), but they were both declined with no explanation. I then mod flagged explaining why they should be deleted, but the mod flags were *also* declined with no explanation. When I reflagged one asking why they were declined and linking to Help Center guidance that indicated those comments shouldn't exist, *that* comment was declined, again with no explanation.

These are the two comments:

> Do you mean you need `\b70\d{7}\b`? Why do you always try to add `[0-9]`? Your last regex would work if you removed `[0-9]`

and

> `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`. Whenever you write `[0-9]\d{7}` it's like you were writing `\d\d{7}`, which is equivalent to `\d{8}`. This is why your regexes match 10 digits instead of 9. Drop `[0-9]` and it'll work fine.

I can certainly understand why the NLN flags may have initially been declined; mods don't always check the full context of a flag, and the first comment is arguably asking clarification questions in addition to providing an answer (though the full context would show that's clearly not the case, and that the commenter was not interested in a response from OP). What I can't understand is why the subsequent flags explaining the problem were declined as well.

Here is my explanation in the mod flags:

> This is an answer posted as a comment. It should not be posted as such, on top of the fact that there exists an answer posted as an answer. It is squarely "No longer needed"

<sub>I would actually love to provide substantially more information than this nearly every time I mod flag, but unfortunately mod flags are limited to a very short 200 characters.</sub>

Ironically, my comment notifying the offending commenters to please post answers as answers instead of as comments *was* deleted.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment, comments are **not** supposed to be used for:

> Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)

So why were these flags declined and the offending comments kept? I don't really care about the declined flags against my flagging record (I flag often enough that it won't affect a ban); I am mostly interested in answers not being posted as comments where an existing answer already covers the same material, especially by users who ought to know better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that we had this discussion on MSO earlier, but I am not able to find that. Here is a related discussion on CRMSE  https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8874/answering-questions-in-comments/8875#8875

Comment: I think you should also mention the fact that post was closed as simple typographical error and then reopened. Pointing to a trivial mistake in the comments is justified in my opinion, if you are also voting to close the question.

Comment: @ayhan First, a trivial error is not an off-topic close reason, and shouldn't really weigh that heavily on the fact that an answer should be posted as an answer, not as a comment. Second, the question was *wrongly* closed as a typographical error; that's why it was reopened; the question's closure/open status is irrelevant to the problem of the comments here.

Comment: @BhargavRao Not sure I follow; in this case, the comments were wrongly made the instant they were posted. They were then additionally *obsolete/redundant* after I posted my answer, which came *before* the first flags. I don't see any scenario where, at least after the explanatory mod flags came, the comments should not be deleted. The comments both also were sufficient to serve as complete answers to the question, not just partial observations.

Comment: I was referring to the question in the title, just because a user has posted an answer as a comment, it doesn't mean that the comment should be flagged. The keyword in the help page is "not recommended". Users are _not recommended_ to post answers as comments, but the comments as such are not flag-able.  (also, we can't reply to a comment flag)

Comment: @BhargavRao I didn't know about the lack of ability to add reasons on flag handling for comments, but *declining* such a flag seems a little rude, IMHO. Anyway, yes it technically says "not recommended", but first, it says "When ***shouldn't*** I comment". "Shouldn't" in bold and italics seems pretty clear to me that it... *should not be done*.

Comment: The "recommended" part overrules the "Shouldn't" part in the help pages, @Tyler. In a slightly related discussion: The help pages are tailored to cater to the network as a whole. On the network there are many sites which strongly forbid answers posted as comments. Sites which 1. are discussion based (IPS, Workplace, Academia, etc) 2. are small in size, which want posters to post answers to increase the answered %. On SO, we do allow users to post answers as comments https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments

Comment: @BhargavRao Why do you think a secondary descriptor would overrule a header that is also both bold *and* italicized? Do you have some source (e.g. meta post) that makes that determination? Anyway, that link you provided doesn't actually make a determination, it's just 1 random user asking about the issue and another offering a hypothesis *why*. The answer doesn't make an attempt to claim that it's either OK or not.

Comment: @BhargavRao  And again, the comments in this case don't even match the description in the accepted answer there. These two comments were posted right off the bat *as complete answers*. There was no organic discussion that "led to a solution". It was just "bam, here's the first and second comment both providing a solution for OP's question along with explanation". I can't say for certain without checking, but I seem to recall every prior NLN flag I've cast on a comment answering the question has been deleted. This seems like a stark departure from policy to me.

Comment: There is this meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340572/should-attempts-to-answer-a-question-through-comments-be-flagged. (Oh and BTW, "random" users post meta questions, and "random" users answer it ... but the community as a whole decides whether the agree to it by upvoting it, or otherwise). The other NLN flags should probably have been declined, but I delete comments posted as answers, if the answerer has moved them to an answer, or if the content in the comment has been included in some one else's answer. (Also, I didn't decline any of your flags here)

Comment: Upvoting because of perceived value in the continued existence of this question and the discussion contained within, not because of agreement or any other nonsense.

Comment: @BhargavRao 7 upvotes on a question is hardly community consensus. And by "random user" I mean someone who is not a moderator or employee. For example, I think [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/2756409) is exactly the kind of thing that should be used to indicate Meta consensus instead; it's an authoritative source (a moderator) giving direct, actionable instructions, and it's got a score of 390. That's not only a much higher score than both the ones you linked, it's also directly addressing *what to do*.

Comment: That answer doesn't say anything about deleting said comments. bsides, mods aren't policy makers. I wouldn't take a post by a mod saying X is X as any more of an authoritative response than you or I saying it.

Comment: @TylerH, I'd be very careful to call users from the community as "random". Remember that mods are not kings who rule over the community, stamping their views on everyone and suspending users who're against them. Mods follow the general rule set by users from the community.

Comment: @BhargavRao Trust me, I'm not one to kowtow as a matter of policy :-) But mods help guide policy enforcement and are in contact with CMs as necessary to get additional/more professional guidance, and the community elects them to be representative of the behavior we want to see. Typically when someone asks a question about how they "should" handle something in the system, a mod providing such guidance should be relied upon as much as if not more than a non-mod, as mods *should* know the right answer for the community, *plus* additional info/context not available to other (random) users.

Answer (score 43):

I declined these flags, and I fully expected this to become a point of discussion on Meta. Your growing insistence was clearly evident as you continued to flag the same comments repeatedly. I'm not sure what you were hoping to accomplish by so doing, other than annoying the moderators. Mission accomplished.

Let's unpack this one step at a time.

First, you flagged the comments as "no longer needed". I declined those flags for essentially the reason you cite in the question. It was not at all obvious to me why those comments were "no longer needed". They looked relevant, on-topic, helpful, and constructive. They were not requesting a clarification that had since been provided. They did not appear to be referring to an old revision of the question. I scrutinized things pretty carefully, in fact, and, although I am not a regular expressions expert, I did not find any conceivable argument that could be made in favor of deleting those comments. As such, I declined the flags.

Then, you flagged the comments again with a custom flag, explaining your rationale for flagging as "no longer needed". Unfortunately, your basis for flagging these comments as "no longer needed" was incorrect. The fact that a comment could be interpreted as an answer to the question does *not* justify flagging it as "no longer needed". Comment flags have two possible outcomes: either the flag is declined and the comment is kept, or the flag is marked helpful and the comment is deleted. Deleting a comment that conveys useful information is incredibly stupid and harmful, so I'm not going to do that.

I am *strongly* opposed to deleting comments because they "should have been posted as an answer". First, that assessment is thoroughly subjective. [Obviously the person who posted the comment didn't feel that it was of acceptable quality to be posted as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments), or they would have done so. If you disagree, then you can post an answer. But [that is not a justification for deletion of the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342342/should-we-flag-comments-that-are-only-posted-as-quick-answers?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment438086_342342). Second, even if you could objectively prove that the comment should have been posted as an answer, the fact remains that *it wasn't*. The fact that you think the comment could/should have been posted as an answer *proves* that the comment provides a significant amount of value. It is *utterly foolish* to *destroy value* by deleting a comment because you think it breaks some kind of rule. That's cutting off one's nose to spite the face.

The argument could be (and, indeed, has been) made that [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) says "Comments are not recommended for…[a]nswering a question or providing an alternative solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)." This is absolutely correct. Comments are *not recommended* for answering a question. However, "not recommended" is altogether different from "should be deleted". In particular, "not recommended" puts the onus of judgment on the user who posts the comment. It doesn't define some kind of "rule" that prohibits posting useful, relevant information as a comment

At the risk of repeating myself, **deleting comments because they contain too much information and might therefore be useful to someone is an incredibly stupid notion**, and I categorically refuse to practice it.

Now, there is one additional component of your custom flag, and that is the point that you've since posted an answer to the question, thus (arguably) rendering those comments obsolete. I did not agree with that. Again, I am admittedly not a regular expressions expert, but it looked to me like your answer was distinct from the comments posted by Wiktor and Andrea. I looked sufficiently carefully that I would have noticed obviously identical content, but no harder, because those comments were not causing a problem and therefore there was no motivation to delete them. At worst, they were saying essentially the same thing as your answer. At best, they were providing additional useful information, and you were only flagging them because of a myopic interpretation of what you perceived to be a "rule". I did—and will always—[err on the side of preservation of useful information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379966/what-can-cause-this-questions/379967#379967).

Finally, there was a third set of flags. At this point, I was quite annoyed. The likelihood that I was going to reverse my decision was essentially zero. It appeared to me that you were just raising additional flags to be annoying. The standard workflow for moderator flags is: (1) you flag, (2) a moderator reviews and acts, if appropriate in their judgment, and (3) there is no step 3. At this point, we'd already gone through a further optional "clarification" step, and *still* the moderator disagreed that there was any need to take action. There was no point in flagging it again.

Furthermore, there was no way that I could do what you were <strike>asking</strike> demanding. You didn't quote your third set of flags, so allow me:

> Please explain why these flags are being declined rather than just declining silently. "When shouldn't I comment?" from stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment specifies this as a valid case

**There is no way for moderators to include an explanation for the dispensation of a comment flag.** That option only exists for flags on posts (questions or answers). So, even if I wasn't sufficiently annoyed at this point and *wanted* to provide a detailed explanation, I couldn't do it. I really had no choice but to, once again, decline your flags. Especially because I *still* didn't want to delete the comments you were flagging, because the situation had not changed since I looked at it ten minutes earlier.

You essentially answer your own question right there in the question, albeit without even realizing it:

> So why were these flags declined and the offending comments kept? I don't really care about the declined flags; I am mostly interested in answers not being posted as comments, especially by users who ought to know better.

The flags were declined because **you admittedly didn't care about whether or not the comments were useful and relevant: you only cared about attempting to dole out some kind of "justice" by punishing users whom you thought should "know better"**. Frankly, I felt like *you* should have known better.

---

As for the bonus question of why your admonition not to answer in comments was deleted, I have several responses to that.

First, I can use your own logic against you. If there are any "rules" regarding the appropriate use of comments, it's that they should be meaningful and relevant to the question. Yours wasn't; it was merely meta-commentary about another comment.

Second, and more importantly, that comment had already served its purpose: Wiktor had seen and responded to it:

[image: Screenshot of deleted comments]

That conversation had run its course, was not going to be helpful to future viewers (unlike the comments you flagged), and was not otherwise relevant to the question. Obsolescence is a standard reason to delete comments. As such, I deleted them.

Furthermore, Wiktor's justification for posting his remark as a comment instead of an answer made perfect sense to me: he had voted to close the question. It's standard practice *not* to post an answer to questions you are voting to close. When a gentle nudge in the right direction is required to accompany the closure, a comment is an appropriate way to provide that. The fact that you disagreed with Wiktor's vote to close seemed to be what was driving your responses in the comments and your flags. You quickly got condescending, attempting to explain to Wiktor what a "typo" was:

[image: Screenshot of comments that I should have deleted, but didn't the first time around]

I should have deleted these comments the first time around, but I didn't. *Mea culpa*. I've now corrected that mistake.

Comment: I’ve been waiting for a mod to say this for *years*, so I can quote it. Common sense rules the day. What a relief!

Comment: @DanBron this has nothing to do with common sense, it is purely site-specific tradition to consider such comments okay, and I know other sites where attempts at answers in comments are ruthlessly wiped out.

Comment: ...it looks particularly funny when such sites questions get to hot network list and gangs of SO passers-by armed with association bonus (and thinking every site culture is the same as at SO) get to comments and start polluting with half-answers, only to have all their mess removed in an hour or two

Comment: I guess the converse is also true, and explains why we get so many non-answers posted in the answer box on Stack Overflow. I'd prefer that the "mess" exist in the comments than in the answers. I also submit that this is *absolutely* common sense. Deleting valuable contributions because you personally think that they should instead have been posted as an answer is not at all sensible. The job of a moderator is never to destroy value, at least not on Stack Exchange sites. That is thoroughly perverse. Other sites regularly delete comments that become a *problem*; that's also equally true on SO.

Comment: converse is plainly false because total amount of users at sites with strict opposite policy is, like, 0.001% of those at Stack Overflow. Primary reason for non-answers at SO is long known - 50-rep requirement for comments (to avoid misunderstanding I consider this requirement a good thing). As for belief about how much sense it makes universally, I consider such discussions pointless. If a site has been preserving comments for years I am not interested in changing that culture. Same if another site has removing, I rather accept that part of their norms than pretend that it is somehow wrong

Comment: This is quite unfortunate; I think this answer grossly mischaracterizes the events and the motivations of the subject, in order to come to a position that is not only wrong (and harmful to SO, in my opinion), but furthermore, and just as importantly, your response contains several problematic, untrue, and/or misleading statements/arguments. I'll try to go through them each.

Comment: *"Your growing insistence was clearly evident as you continued to flag the same comments repeatedly. I'm not sure what you were hoping to accomplish by so doing, other than annoying the moderators. Mission accomplished."* This seems kinda rude of you; I flagged the comments as NLN in good faith, and I re-flagged with a mod-flag explanation in good faith, too. I even asked for an explanation in good faith, but unfortunately I didn't know mods couldn't provide explanations on comment flags. *Mea culpa*.

Comment: That you think I was trying to annoy moderators or some other childish thing is frustrating; I would hope you or any mod would recognize that as a long-time prolific flagger, editor, and otherwise curator of the site, that my actions were sincere. Moderators *especially* should assume good faith. It's hurtful to see you didn't do that here in my case and instead assumed ill intent.

Comment: *"I did not find any conceivable argument that could be made in favor of deleting those comments"* The existence of the same content in an answer didn't jump out at you? I'm not a regex expert either, but a solution existing in an answer makes the same solution existing in a comment unneeded 100% of the time. Otherwise, what's the point of even having the answer function? Comments are not for answers or solutions, they're for clarification requests or suggestions to improve the post. Users can't edit a comment, can't downvote it for inaccuracy, can't accept it as the solution.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, your basis for flagging these comments as "no longer needed" was incorrect"* Actually it is quite factually correct; the content existed in a more appropriate form: an answer. This seems to be the crux around which your entire... diatribe, for lack of a better word, is constructed. *"The fact that a comment could be interpreted as an answer to the question does not justify flagging it as "no longer needed"* First, these comments aren't being "interpreted" as an answer; they *are* answers. They answer OP's question by giving a solution and they provide supporting explanations.

Comment: Second, I didn't flag it as NLN simply because it was an answer to the question. I flagged it as NLN because it was not only an answer in a comment (problematic in and of itself), but also crucially because it was *no longer needed* thanks to the answer I had posted with the same solution and reasoning. If that's not what 'no longer needed' means, then it doesn't mean anything at all. *"Deleting a comment that conveys useful information is incredibly stupid and harmful, so I'm not going to do that."* I agree. Luckily, deleting these comments wouldn't have removed any useful information.

Comment: *"Obviously the person who posted the comment didn't feel that it was of acceptable quality to be posted as an answer, or they would have done so."* Actually it's obvious from his request for closure of that Q and myriad comments throughout the page that the person didn't think the question deserved to exist at all. Not to mention they consistently applied an inaccurate close reason. This whole paragraph of yours just repeats the wrong claim for why I was flagging (again, I flagged the comments as "no longer needed", *because **there was an answer** that said those things*).

Comment: *"deleting comments because they contain too much information and might therefore be useful to someone is an incredibly stupid notion"* And at the risk of repeating myself, **this is not why I flagged the comments for deletion**, and at this point it seems pretty clear that you set out in writing this post to tar me for some reason by making it look like I had some ridiculously off-base reason for flagging the comments.

Comment: *"Now, there is one additional component of your custom flag, and that is the point that you've since posted an answer to the question, thus (arguably) rendering those comments obsolete."* Frankly this is where your answer and reasoning should begin. Even though the conclusion that follows is wrong IMO, it's at least defensible; the first half of your answer is not.

Comment: *"Finally, there was a third set of flags. At this point, I was quite annoyed."* A third set' of flags No, there was one flag asking for explanation. You know, *guidance*, so that future declined flags can hopefully be avoided. If a user requesting guidance annoys you, that's not a very good thing for a moderator. I would hope at the point a moderator gets annoyed that they step away and/or let another moderator handle the issue. *"There is no way for moderators to include an explanation for the dispensation of a comment flag."* This has already been covered by Bhargav above.

Comment: *"The flags were declined because you admittedly didn't care about whether or not the comments were useful and relevant: you only cared about attempting to dole out some kind of "justice" by punishing users whom you thought should "know better". Frankly, I felt like you should have known better."* This is not at all an accurate representation of what my comment says, though I can see how you could misinterpret it to say that. I'll explain how you've misinterpreted it in the next comment, but it's a little ridiculous to try and use such a comment as *ex post facto* justification.

Comment: Now, as for my statement, when I said I don't care about declined flags, I meant I don't care about having declined flags shown in my record. It's not about rectifying the *flag*, but about rectifying the *problem on SO Main* that I encountered. And yes, I think the users ought to know better, but I'm not "seeking justice" against users (I don't hold any ill will toward the people who posted the comments), nor do I think deleting comments is "punishing" the users who posted them. That's just absurd.

Comment: *"As for the bonus question of why your admonition not to answer in comments was deleted"* I didn't ask such a question, so I will just assume this strawman section is a continuance of your frustration. It's unfortunate though that my attempt to help Wiktor came across to you as condescension. He displayed a clear lack of understanding of the term and close reason, so I tried to explain it to him in chat, when that failed and he posted the same wrong justification on the comments, I shared the link & explanation there for not only Wiktor, but for the benefit of other potential CVers, too.

Comment: And, to your point of not being a regex expert but "scrutizing things pretty carefully", the 1st paragraph of my answer covers the first two sentences of Andrea's comment under the question. The 2nd paragraph of my answer covers the second and 3rd sentences of Andrea's comment. The ensuing solutions I included cover the last sentence of both Andrea's comment and Wiktor's comment. Considering that, and that Wiktor wrong close-voted, and del-voted both the Q *and* my answer, I think careful, objective scrutiny would reveal that their comments aren't adding any value.

Comment: Why are you so adamant about a Q&A pair that is absolutely useless for anyone other than the OP? There's zero reason for this pair to stay around. *"Why is my regexp to find 9 digits only finding 10? Because your regexp looks for 10..."* This Q&A pair does not deserve this much discussion/emotion.

Comment: @KevinB I saw a problem, so I tried to take appropriate action to correct the problem. When that was stymied, I asked why, because my interest has always been to keep the site as clean and tidy as best I can. Why is that such a problem for you? I agree that ideally no Q&A pair should entail such discussion, but when I or my actions are unfairly maligned/misrepresented by a mod (of all people), I feel obligated to correct the record and hold said mod accountable.

Comment: Claims that this is an unfair malignment or misrepresentation are not defensible. This is a completely accurate account of how I interpreted your actions, and I stand by it. To be clear, there is nothing necessarily wrong with raising a second flag that is more clear/explicit than your first flag. That second set of flags made me look more closely. I just still happened to disagree with you. It was that third set of flags that clearly suggested you were on a mission not to be disagreed with and that caused me to become annoyed.

Comment: As for the elephant in the room, the fact that this discussion just blew up my inbox with 15 comments, can we all agree that that *is* a misuse of the comments feature? If what you are trying to comment doesn't fit in the comment box, then it probably shouldn't be a comment.

Comment: @CodyGray To be clear, you're standing by the fact that you've entirely made up a reason for why I flagged, despite me having now refuted that reason quite clearly and explicitly?

Comment: @CodyGray And as for the elephant in the room, I'd be happy to discuss things in chat, where I think you know (if not, color me surprised, but now you know) I am almost always available in case you need to, for example, point out that mods can't reply to comment flags and that you disagree that answers-as-comments are not useless despite an actual answer covering the same material being present. To me, at least, that would be a textbook example of *great* moderation.

Answer (score 6):

Here goes an unsolicited third opinion.

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835164/2751851) is essentially equivalent to the comments by Wiktor Stribiżew and Andrea Corbellini (though I like the phrasing of Andrea's comment slightly better than yours). That means there might have been a decent case for removing the comments as "No Longer Needed". *However*, reconstituting the history of the Q&A from your question here and [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384218/2751851) leads me to conclude that you went about it the wrong way, and the outcome being discussed here is unsurprising. Allow me to explain:

- Though you made your answer community wiki, the answer itself does not mention Wiktor and Andrea's comments. Doing that would have made your intent clearer (in addition to being good attribution etiquette). Changing the opening sentence to "As Wiktor Stribiżew and Andrea Corbellini have pointed out in comments, [...]" would have been enough (the link to the regex reference could have been inlined into the following sentence).
- In a similar way, while your first custom flag pointedly notes that "there exists an answer posted as an answer", it doesn't mention your answer was intended to replace the comments. I believe something like "I have posted an answer equivalent to the comments by Wiktor Stribiżew and Andrea Corbellini, and so it is fine to remove those comments now" would have been far more likely to lead to the outcome you desired. As it actually happened, you were, in effect, asking the mods to make a snap judgement on the technical equivalence between answer and comments, when the responsibility of clarifying that falls squarely on the shoulders of the flag caster.

The above is sufficient to explain why I believe Cody's handling of the flags was appropriate. It is worth noting a few more things about the surrounding events:

- There are several circumstances which make it reasonable to post answer-like content in comments. One of them is believing a question should be closed as "Off-topic/Typo" or as a duplicate and posting an answer-like comment to clarify that. Wiktor believes the question should be closed, and so he chose to point out the problem with the OP's code in a comment. It is fine to disagree with his reasoning, but the discussion about whether the question should indeed be closed as a typo is completely separate from that about whether Wiktor was justified in posting the comment. That being so, your "[...] especially by users who ought to know better" remark feels out of place.
- By the way, "For your benefit en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error" does come across as very condescending. That that comment was posted after a chat discussion with Wiktor doesn't really change that.
- Lastly, it seems quite clear to me that casting a custom flag isn't a very good pathway for disputing the outcome of a custom flag, or asking for an explanation thereof. Even accounting for you believing that mods could address comments to you via comment flags, posting your Meta question right after the first custom flag was declined would have been more appropriate.

Comment: I knew the solution to the issue independently of the comments from Andrea and Wiktor; it just so happens that the solution was a very straightforward one, necessitating quite similar explanations. I made it a CW out of an abundance of deference, but I didn't rely on their comments to write the answer, so providing attribution would've been inaccurate/incorrect. As for the custom flag, it's true, I could have made it more explicit in the flag dialog that the effective content of the answer directly superseded the content of the comments, but unfortunately I was out of allowed characters, IIRC.

Comment: Regarding custom flag being a good pathway or not, I didn't (and still don't, after seeing Cody's reasoning) think a Meta Q is necessary to address why the flags were declined, considering first that the actual reasoning amounts to, basically, "I disagree that the comments are no longer needed", and second that, when I raised the third flag asking why the first two were declined, I was thinking there must have been some technical reason for why the flags were declined, as it is so glaringly clear that the comments are in fact not needed. [1/2]

Comment: Had I known that mods are not able to leave a note/reason when handling comment flags, I definitely would not have raised the third flag, and may or may not have asked a question on Meta at all. [2/2]

Comment: @TylerH On CW: what you did is understandable, though it feels somewhat of a half measure to me. I would either have gone all the way and made it CW with explicit attribution, or not made it CW (which would have been entirely justified here, as you came up with the answer independently).