# What should I do if it seems like a user is deliberately retaliating?

Tags: discussion, abuse

I recently asked a question, [mentioning (in the very first version of the question) why a particular technique wasn't suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958301/is-it-possible-to-create-different-shadow-colors-on-different-sides-using-css-bo).

A user marked the question as a duplicate of another, which stated to use the technique that I had mentioned did not work for this problem.

SO's automated tool asked me to edit my work to show the difference. As I had already specified why that technique did not help in the original edit, and I was angry the user didn't bother to read the question, I left [a rather shouty edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58958301/3) **drawing attention to what I'd already written in my initial release of the question**. I don't like to shout, but it felt like nobody was reading the question, when the question:

- mentioned I was aware of that technique's existence in the question in the very first version
- mentioned why it was not appropriate for the question in the very first version
- linked to the official docs for that technique in the question in the very first version

The angry edit was removed (which I can understand) but it looks like the moderator, rather than acknowledging the question wasn't a duplicate, marked it as being 'unspecific'.

> I believe 'unspecific' was a deliberate retaliation - the question's title is 'Is it possible to create different shadow colors on different sides using CSS box-shadow?' which is incredibly specific.

Oddly many users seem to have found the question interesting as there were [many answers, including two particularly good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961742/123671) sent both on chat and on discussion.

**How should I handle a user who seems to be retaliating to a user pointing out errors in their marking decisions?**

Comment: your question was never closed as duplicate and no moderator was involved in closing your question.

Comment: I see no diamond moderators involved except for one who rolled back some rather rude text you added (back) to the question. The only people involved in closing the question were users with high rep and gold badges...

Comment: @Temani Afif The Stack Overflow UI said the question was marked as duplicate and nobody was able to answer it. Does that not count as being closed as duplicate? In addition could you please not downvote well written questions without explaining why? I'm trying to handle this constructively and would appreciate some courtesy.

Comment: I haven't really played with the New and Improved™ Close Message Dialogs, but I would presume that it would not only indicate that it was closed as a duplicate, but offer links *to* the duplicate.  That does not appear to be the case - it looks like it was closed as "needs more focus".

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I was using moderator in the colloquial sense of 'someone doing moderaton'. I'll edit the question accordingly to avoid the term.

Comment: you should simply stop accusing me of downvoting because you don't know if I did it. As a side note I was the one who help you by giving a related question in the comment which is a duplicate but I voted to close for another reason. (I am asking another Gold badge to do btw)

Comment: *I'm trying to handle this constructively* ... well then I'd recommend you read a bit more about moderation on SO ...

Comment: @Temani Afif Apologies if you didn't downvote, you seemed to be the only person viewing this question on meta, and as you're not disinterested (you also moderated the original question) it seemed like it may have been you. If it wasn't I'm sorry.

Comment: @Jonas Wilms OK. What should I read? Is there another question that handles users who get angry about being called out on not reading questions?

Comment: I'd recommend [closure reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and [What if I disagree?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) in the help center ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks but none of them handle the issue of "being asked to clarify something you've explicitly clarified in your question". if you have something on that though please let me know.

Comment: Actually @jonas the last part of 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions' is quite helpful. " Any question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue," Maybe next time I can ignore the user asking me to edit the question to include content it already does and simply address the review queue.

Comment: Explain why you think the question should be reopened in the comments, and *objectively*. Then vote to reopen. If the reviewers don't agree to you, come here to Meta.

Comment: Yup, exactly. That's what the reopen queue is for (if it would work correctly)

Comment: You keep combining the closure with duplication. This wasn't closed as a duplicate - you don't have to explain how it's not a duplicate to reopen it. It was closed for entirely different reason.

Comment: @VLAZ Ack, it was 1. marked as a duplicate (or potential duplicate) then 2. flagged for a different reason. I believe 2 happened as a retaliation for pointing out the users were mistaken for 1.

Comment: I don't believe that *five* different users all decided to attack you at once.

Comment: @VLAZ I believe that users don't like it being demonstrated that they haven't actually read questions.

Comment: One user commented that it might be a duplicate.  Because the displayed close reason was too broad a majority of people closed it for that reason not because they felt it was a duplicate.

Comment: @DanNeely: honestly, how is "Is it possible to create different shadow colors on different sides using CSS box-shadow?" inspecific?

Comment: @dan I'm sorry but that makes no sense at all. Each voter should make it's own judgement.

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)  (also, possibly related: [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773))

Comment: @gnat that's a good resource, if someone had mentioned that was why they thought the question was vague I'd have happily re-worded it to "How can I create different shadow colors on different sides using CSS box-shadow?" or similar. But it never came up in discussion.

Comment: You seem to think people are way more invested in the question than they probably are. We see dozens of questions a day. Sometimes we make mistakes - I've misread or misvoted multiple times. I don't hold it against anybody if they point this out. After all, I might read upwards of a hundred question a day (well, not all days). I definitely go through multiple hundreds a week. Dunno about others but I don't tend to cling onto a single question that hard as you seem to imply *five other people* did with yours.

Comment: @VLAZ I think people are pretty invested in the question if [the sudden torrent of downvotes since I posted on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958301/is-it-possible-to-create-different-shadow-colors-on-different-sides-using-css-bo) are anything to go by.

Comment: @mikemaccana See [What is the Meta Effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) to learn more about that topic. A meta question's tone has a *lot* to do with its reception by the community, even if you are ultimately right. Trust me, I have [experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384217/why-were-my-comment-flags-declined-for-comments-that-provided-answers).

Comment: @mikemaccana you are confusing [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) with people being specifically interested in this one question.

Comment: @VLAZ Wouldn't the meta effect (as discussed there) describe people becoming specifically interested in a question?

Comment: No, it's people who go to the question because there is a link to it, not because they feel attached to this specific question to such an extent to take to false close voting when something about that question insults them.

Comment: @VLAZ People do. It happens all the time. (in reply to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391528/what-should-i-do-if-it-seems-like-a-user-is-deliberately-retaliating#:~:text=I%20don%27t%20believe%20that%20five%20different%20users%20all%20decided%20to%20attack%20you%20at%20once. )

Answer (score 19):

Am I missing something here?  Only *one* moderator's been involved with this question, and that was to roll back the edit you made to your post.

[Here's the history of that.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58958301/timeline)

If you're upset that five others closed your question, then...well...the best thing to do would be to [not pick](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58961742/1) [a fight](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58958301/9) with [the people](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58958301/5) who [closed it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58958301/3) in the first place.

Instead, engage somewhere like on Meta asking how the question could be improved.  Be humble rather than defensive.  Otherwise you're going to run head-first into a brick wall of apathy.

Comment: *If you're upset that five others closed your question* ---> and unfortunately a  *bit*  unfriendly: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58958301/5

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. I don't mean 'moderator' as in 'diamond moderator', I mean a user doing moderation. I mentioned that above and I'v edited the question.

Comment: In addition, saying I 'picked a fight' when [**you're entirely aware of how the conflict started**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58958301/timeline#comment_104172049) is disingenuous.

Comment: @Temani Afif It's unfriendly to not bother reading something before closing it. I've mentioned this to you multiple times, if you have some reason to disagree please state so.

Comment: "a user doing moderation" is not usually called a "moderator". Mostly a diamond mod is called that although sometimes newer users also call gold badge holders "moderator". At any rate, there were *five* people who closed the question and it wasn't for being a duplicate. Moreover, I can't see anybody voting for a dupe - there is a *comment* suggesting it is related and maybe a duplicate but doesn't appear to be generated from a dupe vote.

Comment: @mikemaccana:  You assume I read the comment thread.   To be fair we could've avoided all of this plot had you flagged that comment for removal and left it alone.

Comment: Thanks @vlax for clarifying SO's terminology here. The question was marked as a duplicate, then (after the lack of duplication originally mentioned) shut down as 'vague' by the user I believe were retaliating.

Comment: @Makoto I assume you would read the history of a question before accusing me of starting the fight, yes. You should have.

Comment: I see no trace of it being marked as a dupe in [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58958301/timeline). One comment and then later it was closed as "too broad" but completely unrelated people,

Comment: @VLAZ all I can say is what I saw in the SO UI - it might have been marked as  'possible duplicate' rather than 'duplicate' etc but it was marked as a duplicate of 'use multiple shadows' in SO, a technique that was mentioned in the question in it's very first version.

Comment: The one permanent record in all of this, @mikemaccana, is the question edits.  The comments can be deleted and then the history of such won't even matter since deleted comments aren't preserved in there.  In essence, *now* you're trying to debate *me* on some procedural technicality when it all boils down to **don't edit fighting words into your question, irrespective of how you feel about things**.  I admit I'm surprised that someone with your rep level is not in the know about how to flag comments.

Comment: @makoto Totally agreed, as mentioned in the question I don't like to shout and I regret doing so. I didn't want to. When your question says 'I know about multiple shadows' and another user has made you edit the question that says you know about multiple shadows to prove you know about multiple shadows - **can you understand the frustration?** I'm asking this question to try and find an alternative.

Comment: Then next time, @mikemaccana?  **Don't shout.** We could've avoided all of this had you flagged the comment instead of making it a bigger deal than it needed to be.

Comment: No, that wouldn't have fixed the issue. **Flagging the comment doesn't fix bad flagging of the question**: how do you edit the question that already says you know about multiple shadows, to prove you know about multiple shadows? You could add a heading that says **hey I know about multiple shadows** but that's shouting. What else can users do?

Answer (score 13):

*What to do if everybody else is wrong and closed my question, eventhough it is a perfect question?*

Here's an (attempt to) answer:

**Step 1: Get some fresh air.** Seriously. If there are a lot of comments and downvotes and negativity, it *won't get onto the right track again* with even more comments and downvotes and negativity. Break the vicious circle. Step out. Cool down. Do other stuff. Then...

**Step 2: Understand the context.** Question everything. *What is a question, actually?* *What is a closure?* *What are review queues?* *How does moderation work?*

Understand that there are *just humans* at the other end of the wire. humans with emotions. Humans that aren't always correct. Humans that look at hundreds of mostly crappy questions every day trying to *help people* ... Humans that might not spend their full attention onto your question. That might skip some sentences. That might click the wrong button by accident. Humans that might get angry if they are questioned. Humans that are *always right*.  Humans that tend to defend their own "group" (i.e. the close voters).

Understand that *questions are just sand*. That closure is a mandatory mechanism to actually deliver good answers to good questions.

Understand that the same words contain different meanings.

If you know it all, you can ...

**Step 3: Analyze the situation.** Go into a third person view. Ignore emotions and feelings, focus on facts. *Which user saw which version of the question? Which user wrote wich comment? * *Which user took which action?*

**Step 4: Question your own steps.**

*Was that comment rude? Should I apologize? Was my question on-topic?*

In case you are angry again at this step, continue with step 1.

**Step 5: Talk!**
Ask for clarification and additional information. Question actions, not people.

In case you are angry again at this step, continue with step 1.

**Step 6: Get more eyes on it!**
Explain your situation. Vote to reopen (if the *closure* was wrong), flag for moderator attention (if others were getting too personal too), take it to the Meta high court.

**Step 7: What's next?**

If you went this far ... and *everybody else* still thinks you are wrong ... Well, maybe then ... it could theoretically be that ...

---

Some additional comments on your case:

> angry the user didn't bother to read the question, I left a rather shouty edit drawing attention to what I'd already written in my initial release of the question.

Great! Thats a very good first step. You are questioning your own steps, you acknowledge that this might've been the wrong way to answer.

You asked polite questions here on Meta.

That was really good too.

But then you ...

... still called other *humans* "retaliatory users" and went back to Step 1.

Comment: I called them retaliatory as they were retaliating. That's not an insult, that's a statement.

Comment: And how does that "statement" help? *Question actions, not users*

Comment: Saying that someone is being retaliatory is *precisely* questioning their actions. I could have said they were (insert thing here) but instead I very deliberately focused on the actions. No objections to your answer though, it's certainly more helpful than the other one.

Comment: Don't question *their action*, question *the action*

Answer (score -16):

**How should I handle a user who seems to be retaliating to a user pointing out errors in their marking decisions?**

The other answer above doesn't handle how to handle a user who is marking a question as a duplicate without reading the content, except to say that one shouldn't shout to point out the content they missed.

**That's true, but it doesn't show what one *should* do to get their non-duplicate question seen.**

## Avoid addressing potential retaliatory users in comments

Commenting about marking errors in discussion doesn't seem to work - while it may be the 'official' way to handle marking discussion, many users don't like their marking decisions being called into question and (as can be seen by the retaliation downvotes on the question since posting on Meta) SO is an adversarial environment at times.

However I'd like to add something more constructive @jonas above pointed out, via https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions:

> ## The review queue
>
> Any question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue

A better way to handle users incorrectly marking questions as duplicates would be addressing reviewers which will eventually be seen by the review queue.

Comment: One problematic thing here is your assumption that a specific user has "not read the content". First, you should assume good faith. The [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) specifically says to avoid claims like "*If you bothered to read my question, you’d know it’s not a duplicate.*" Second, consider that a user with a gold badge in the language you're asking for help with *might just know more than you*. If you still think they're wrong, edit your question as best you can to point out the differences as you see them. Ultimately, the community will decide how it views your Q.

Comment: (N.B. - I've not currently voted up, down, or otherwise on this answer, this question, or the question on main).

Comment: @TylerH "If you still think they're wrong, edit your question as best you can to point out the differences as you see them. " I did that even before they asked, specifically mentioning why that technique wouldn't work in my original post.

Comment: Great, so at that point you've done due diligence. Now it's up to the community to decide whether they agree with you or not. In this case, five separate people felt your question was unclear or needed more details. A dozen or so edits later, your question was reopened by four *other* users (and yourself). This looks to me like a system that's working fine. Once you've resolved issues brought up in comments (like in the case I just described), you should flag the respective comments as "no longer needed". You can usually get a jumpstart on that process by self-deleting any comments made by you

Comment: How does this answer "*How should I handle a user who seems to be retaliating to a user pointing out errors in their marking decisions?*"

Comment: Your question shouldn't address anyone. It should be a question and stand on its own. Just like any 'hi or 'thanks in advanced' is fluff, any bit of your question 'adressed at someone' is fluff as well that shouldn't be in, IMHO.

Comment: "This looks to me like a system that's working fine." well it feels *awful*. I should't have to be ignored b yusers who liek downvoting things without reading them, then campaign to ask users who want to answer to reopen. I shouldn't have another wave on downvotes on the original question since asking here. SO feels like a MOBA.

Comment: @Patrice good point, I guess you're saying leave discussion in discussion? But SO asks me to edit my post to add content (about why it's not a dupe) that's already in my post.

Comment: @mikenaccana that you believe is clear. That a group of others don't think is. You can ask a friend to check and ask them at the end if they get your point about that point. You can take a break, remove the question for now, step away, check it once rested, and maybe then you'll find another way of writing this? Overall, a lot of the stance feels VERY adversarial. I am just.... Not sure it'll be productive in any way, shape or form :/

Comment: @scohe001 it covers "what one should do to get their non-duplicate question seen".

Comment: That's all well and good, but I'm not sure how this answers the question you posted. Was that what you were trying to ask with this meta question all along? If so, maybe you should update your question.

Comment: Of course, this is all covered in the (now perhaps poorly titled) FAQ: [“This question may already have an answer here” - but it does not - or - What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/215552)

Comment: @Patrice Well yes, SO is an adversarial environment as demonstrated. Not just in the retaliation to the original marking errors but also the retaliation downvotes to the original question since posting here.

Comment: In my defense, my answer never covered the duplicate scenario since your question was never closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @mikemaccana you do know it takes 2 sides to have a fight? SO isn't an easy environment, but ppl need to stop reacting emotionally, agressively, and negatively. On both sides. Or nothing changes. And then ppl come to meta, half cocked, and end up ruffling feathers. Then the ruffled ones retaliate, then everyone loses. Ain't it a nice story? All we need is to *not start*. Just that. Not jump into an adversarial mode as soon as everything doesn't go our way. Then.... Maybe we can all make these experiences better?

Comment: @Patrice Yep. I've edited the answer above to provide more info on not interacting with adversarial users by using review queue instead of discussion.

Comment: @Makoto Sure. Action 1 'duplicate' was a warning, and action 2 'vagueness' was close, which as previously discussed here, was in response to my pointing out the errors concerning 1.

Comment: @mike do you see that with a stance of 'ppl on the site won't be reasonable' you are being very adversarial? It's the irony of the whole thing.... To work together on a shared goal, we actually have to.... *Work*.... *Together*.....

Comment: @patrice that is not my stance. If you are unsure of my stance please ask me.