# Comment or post answer

Tags: discussion, support

I'm new to answering and comment on SO and see a lot of people answering the question as a comment to the post rather than submitting an answer.

What is the correct way?
Should a comment which is the answer be also posted as an answer so it can be marked as the answer?

Comment: @gparyani Correct, that is a duplicate, apologies

Comment: Ideally the OP uses the info to complete his Q+A.  You can do the job for him, but make sure the question is not based on a silly typo or is a duplicate.  It almost always is.

Comment: @HansPassant it was mainly me wanting to ensure that me adding answers was correct and that inl shouldn't be adding comments instead

Comment: Quite often when the problem is just a typo, people would point out the problem in comment and vote to close the question. This allows others to also realize it is a typo - and they vote to close too. Sometimes people might post a link to a related question, but may not fully answer the question. But in any event if a high rep user is posting a comment instead of an answer, they certainly know what they are doing.

Comment: @Nisarg (unrelated to this question) Is a "silly" logic error close-able as a typo? (if so is there any meta post?)

Comment: @user202729 I don't think we need a meta for this, a "silly" logic error posted as quetion is sometimes of lack of search ... some usesr directly ask question when the face issues without trying for hours to search the error and at the end we have code missing `;`, using wrong names, bad `ìf else`, etc --> so I think yes close-able as typo

Comment: I think this is also personal preference. I don't like to write basic one-line answers so i comment instead. (something like: _"You should do X instead of Y"_)

Comment: [My take on this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339396/2751851) (in brief: it tends to be better to post solutions as answers, but there can be legitimate reasons to post them as comments instead).