# When should I answer and when should I comment?

Tags: discussion

I am new to Stack Overflow, because I used to find answers on this website, so now I also want to help some people with my simple mind.

I often don't know when I should write down an answer and when I should only comment.

I saw that after someone’s answered was told to should comment, although his answer is correct.
if I just comment, how do I gain reputation? I also have read the help center about [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

**Should I always write down my answer to the comment? when should I answer and when should I comment?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is really not a difficult thing. Just ask yourself a simple question:

Are you *answering the question?*

Note that I said "answering", not "guessing". If you're doing the latter, flag/vote-to-close instead, possibly with a comment asking for more information (note: not a comment suggesting possible solutions based on incomplete information). If you have to guess, then the OP is not providing enough information and you shouldn't be answering it.

If you are providing the information which you know will allow the asker to do something that gets them out of the problem, then it is an answer and it should be posted as such.

Comment: *"answering", not "guessing"* is the most important part of this.

Comment: However, readers please note that sometimes the right action is to not post the answer, especially when the question is a duplicate. In such cases, hammer/vote to close, and then try to massage the duplicate solution to OP's actual problem in the comments.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: If you have to "massage" the dupe in order to answer the question, then it's *not a duplicate*.

Comment: @NicolBolas I disagree. I come across hundreds of questions like these. For example, in the pandas tag, a question may blatantly be a duplicate of a pivoting question, with the only difference being the column names, or other minor changes. Obviously, pivot questions have been asked to death, I shouldn't answer more of them just because the column names differ from those asked in questions previously.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339394/should-i-comment-or-answer?rq=1 surprised no one picked up on this one ;)