# Answer or comment

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Recently I started to answer some questions on Stack overflow in vhdl topics (It's the only subject where I am a bit competent). When there is a question, most of the experimented members answer the question in comments (especillay when it's a very specific question or a bad question).

I also got a downvote when I answer a question where the developper made a syntax error (that was the real reason of his problem and he accepted it).

When I take a look at this post : [Should I comment or answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339394/should-i-comment-or-answer), it seems to be better to answer.

So what should I do :
  - Answer in comments when the question is not "interesting" for the community ?
  - Answer only if there is no answer in comments ?
  - Answer even if the answer is already in comments ?

Comment: Depends though. Answering when it's a typo is bad, as there's a close reason for typos.

Comment: Answer when you know the answer to a question and the question is on-topic.

Comment: Surely there's just so many VHDL questions that can be answered with a comment though?

Comment: (As a side note, while VHDL questions are on-topic on SO, they are perhaps more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com, where they are also perfectly on-topic.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, the process is the following:

1. Should this question be closed? If yes: don't answer

   Questions should be closed if they're off-topic, duplicates of other questions, unclear, too broad, or simple typos. See [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more
2. Am I just guessing? If yes: don't answer, request clarification.

   If my answer is an educated guess, it's likely that the question is unclear or lacks a proper example, or I lack sufficient knowledge to properly answer. I only answer if I'm fairly sure
3. Is the question useful? If no: consider downvoting, don't answer

   Helping people that ask questions of no use to others at all makes it harder for others to find useful information here. This is somewhat subjective, though.

   Note: *there are no bad questions* is a lie we tell children and doesn't hold up in the real world, especially not on Stack Overflow
4. If all the above allow me to answer, and I'm sure I can actually write a good answer here (without relying on off-site resources for usefulness): answer

Simple syntax errors can fail both 1 and 3. They can also be a common mistake so helpful for others, and meet all these criteria. Without more specifics, it's hard to tell

Comment: Had some down-time: http://tinyurl.com/y6yckzma

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Each rule is a bit subjective but I'll try to follow them.