# How should I answer questions I am not 100% certain (if at all)?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am an intermediate answerer within my tag, meaning I am usually knowledgeable enough to solve some of the simpler (syntactical/algorithmic) questions but not experienced enough to say with absolute certainty that my answer is the best solution to a question.

For example, I answered with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64055726/14336931) to one question (excerpt):

> **Likely** the simplest way to do this would be to use list comprehension. This allows for the entire logic to be boiled down to a single line. **...**

Should I have answered the question at all, given that I was not 100% certain; and if so, should I have included the "likely" at the beginning?

My reasoning is that the "likely" serves as additional noise, when my answer could have been completely certain, and, had my answer been wrong/ineffective, the answer itself would have been "noise" (although noise that's controlled by voting). This led me to a few possibilities for answering:

1. Answer only when I am sure my answer is the best one
2. Answer when I am reasonably certain of my answer, not including any uncertain language, and allow the voting/editing system to lead to revision/deletion if necessary
3. Answer when I am reasonably certain, potentially including uncertain language ("probably," "likely," etc.), revising/deleting if necessary

There is a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370133/14336931) on here that focuses on unsure answers, but only when the question itself isn't completely understood. I bring it up because of one (actually two but only at the end) comment on the second answer that applies:

> "You should still post it as an answer to allow others to vet your post" - no, no, no! Answers are not the place for guesses. You're basically advocating that people, who are unsure whether their answer will actually answer the question, should just go ahead and post it, hoping that someone knowledgeable will come along, properly analyse the answer (and not just vote on it by the looks of it) and downvote it if it's incorrect. That's not how answers work. **...** This site is a place for clear, unambiguous questions with definitive answers.

Which leads me to think that the first possibility I outlined is the correct choice (or at least the third one is incorrect).

The main point of this question is that the answer I gave is currently the accepted answer, which wouldn't have been possible if I hadn't answered (although I'm sure someone else could've provided a similar solution). Additionally, I would like to answer questions if I am able to, although I won't if doing so would lead to low-quality answers.

I understand that I'm asking about only a single word, but I want to ensure I'm answering questions in the best way possible.

Comment: If you're not sure but the question is on-topic, there should be enough information in the question to create a MCVE in your IDE or whatever and test your code to see if it works. Once you see that it works, post it. If it doesn't work, you can tweak it until it does work, then post it. If there isn't enough information for such a MCVE, VTC as off-topic - that's better than posting guesses.

Comment: Also, a lot of questions don't have *just one* solution. Even if your answer isn't going to be objectively the best, don't be afraid to post it (as long as it's still following reasonable conventions of whatever programming language is being used)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Would you say that answering with certainty is important (as in getting rid of unsure language)?

Comment: The core of the answer shouldn't be uncertain, but IMO such language is OK around possibly-opinion-based extras (eg: "As a side note, you should probably use `GoodAPI()` instead of `DeprecatedAPI()` unless there's a good reason for it.") or maybe for edge cases not mentioned elsewhere

Comment: “but not experienced enough to say with absolute certainty that my answer is the best solution to a question.” - So don’t answer the question if your unable or not willing to verify the answer is correct.  We typically only want answers that are correct.  I typically downvote answers that are incorrect.  Since were specifically talking about Stack Overflow questions, while there might be multiple correct answers, they keyword is that they are correct.

Comment: By the way as someone who has gone looking for solutions, there isn’t anything I hate more, than an incomplete vague answer that hasn’t been tested by its author for its accuracy

Comment: It's an interesting case scenario. Your answer involves providing the "simplest" way to do it and that is where you usage of the word "likely" came from, because you can't really prove that you have the simplest solution (in the same way, good luck proving that your answer is the best one ever). It doesn't seem that this was actually asked for - the simplest solution. Most of the time, people want something that works - period. And that is the goal of your answer isn't it? To provide something that works? Now ask yourself why you upped the ante unprovoked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually think your option 3 is the best choice.

You're right that it's not a good idea to make a habit of posting answers when you're just guessing, because if you do, a lot of them will wind up being a distraction or spreading bad information. But you don't have to be *absolutely* certain of an answer to post it either. There are plenty of questions out there where only, say, a hundred people in the world are absolutely certain of the answer, but many more people can make a solid educated guess. If those people all decided not to post anything because they're not absolutely sure, the question might never get answered. And it's generally better to have a 90% likely correct answer than no answer at all.

The reason I suggest including language that reflects your uncertainty (i.e. option 3 over option 2) is that that helps readers judge your answer in the proper light. If someone else comes along and leaves an answer that they're absolutely confident in, readers will be able to tell that they're more sure of their answer than you are of yours, and that their answer is probably the better one. Or if someone is using your answer as a reference, if you say that you're not totally sure about it, that person should realize they probably need to double-check with, say, some documentation or some other source before relying on what you're saying.

I think the passage you quoted from that other question doesn't apply to this situation, because the fact that it was talking about unclear questions is crucially important. If the reason you're not sure of your answer is that the question is unclear, different answers might be posted answering the question in different incompatible ways, which makes it hard to evaluate the answers against one another. That's why it should be put on hold so it can be edited before getting answered. But when the question is perfectly clear and you're just not sure of how to answer it, that doesn't apply.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it outlines the cases where uncertain language is beneficial. I know that SO doesn't always work in exact measures, so it makes sense to include language that protects from more "unexactness" by explicitly stating inexperience (in a non-noisy way).

Comment: I really like this answer, since it addresses the reality of the nuance that exists when approaching a question on SO. In all honesty, if no one ever attempted to answer any question they weren't 100% certain on, I think a lot less questions would get answered than currently do. The other reality is that, in programming specifically, *most* answers are easy verified- either the proposed solution works, or it doesn't. Clearly there are exceptions to that, but the gist is that most of the uncertainties I run into regard things like efficiency, not efficacy, which make an answer valid regardless.