# How to properly close a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

It's really not clear for me.

When I add a question, and somebody adds a comment that is enough for me to solve it, how can I properly close the question (and avoid [the Bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420) do it after 28 days)?

Because I will not come back on it after. Or do I need to put myself an answer that shows I succeed with the comment?

Comment: Bots don't automatically close questions. They automatically *delete* them, but if your question has been answered, you don't want to do that, because then you'd be depriving anyone else with the same problem of that answer, which is counter to the whole point of the site. So what is it exactly that you mean by "closing the question"?

Comment: Questions aren't closed because they are answered, they are closed because they are off-topic or unclear. An on-topic question, that isn't a duplicate, will likely remain open forever.

Comment: If this has to do with someone posting an answer in the comments instead of as an actual answer, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat

Comment: If your answer has permanent value, make sure the answer gets into an answer, and not just a comment. If it serves no lasting value, it shouldn't have been asked in the first place. You can close your own question.

Comment: I assume [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335709/should-this-be-an-answer-or-a-comment) is related but tl;dr: yes, feel free to self-answer with your solution (don't just put in a "this comment helped" body).

Comment: *Because I will not come back on it after* - as Gimby answered, you are not so important in this regard. We have tons of questions with more than one, in some cases even a double digit number, answers. Many answers unfortunately just repaeat other answers, but often they have also new approaches/solutions for the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Questions on Stack Overflow are not only for the person that posts it. You did not ask a question so that only you might get an answer as if this is a helpdesk, you essentially donated it to the knowledge base where it should now hopefully start to help many more people from now on. *That* is the goal of the site, to have answers readily available so you do not even have to ask.

Whatever is done with the question must be oriented from that perspective: how will it assist future visitors of the question who have the same or a very similar problem or requirement? An [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [non-duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) question without an answer is not useful to anyone, so someone should provide an answer which is in compliance with the [documented rules and guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) about what makes an answer a valid high quality answer.

If it isn't the author of the comment that tipped you off who also authors the answer, it could just as easily be you yourself.

[Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) do **not** count as answers, no matter how well they are written.

Comment: ^this + on-topic, non-duplicate answers remain open, so that other users can add their answers too (with different approaches/solutions to the same problem).

Answer (score -8):

I understand that a question is satisfied with an answer rather than a comment, with a minimum of technical description to be useful to others.